# Programmatically stop Spring batch parallel flows synchronized on BlockingQueue

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring Batch job that basically reads from a file, processes each line and writes to an output (another file).
Since the processing step is costly I want to have it run in multiple threads, but since the reading and writing steps are using files, those steps must be run on a single thread. 
I ended up having 3 flows, each running in parallel, with one step each, synchronized on 2 BlockingQueues. 
The read step reads from the file and writes to one queue. 
The processing step is multi-threaded and reads from the queue, processes and writes to another queue.
The write step, reads from the second queue and writes the output to another file.

It works pretty well, except that i can't find a clean and 'fast' way to stop the job when everything is done. Right now i'm using 'poll' with a timeout on both queues, and assuming that if no item is present for some amount of seconds, then we're done. This delays the job termination by the specified amount of seconds, and i can't use a very small amount of time because by some external force (like machine load) the job can suffer delays.

I tried using something like a Poison Pill, but the problem is that if i override the 'doRead' method on the FlatFileItemReader to return a Poison Pill when it gets a 'null' (signifying end-of-file) then this reader will never end and the job never terminates.

Does anyone have a suggestion? From the documentation i know that i could probably just put a "synchronized" on the reader from the read Step (file) and on the writer in the Write Step (file), but i'd really prefer a different solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a stateful variable in your reader to track the end of the job.

```
public PoisoningReader<T> extends FlatFileItemReader<T> {
    private boolean endJob = false;

    @Override
    public T doRead() {
        if (endJob) {
            return null;
        }

        T object = super.doRead();
        if (object == null) {
            endJob = true;
            return new PoisonPill();
        }
        return item;
    }
```

Comment: Hadn't thought about it. Was trying to keep the reader stateless, but yeah it should do the trick.

Comment: Just make sure to set `scope="step"` if you're multithreading the reader so each one gets its own instance variable. Also, you may want to make sure the blocking queue is persistent depending on your failure/restart scenarios.

Comment: Yeah, i already have the scoping working. The queues are in-memory only, and job-scoped, beause i dont really need the restarting/resuming automatically features.

Comment: So i tried you solution and it works partially in my scenario. The problem is that i have 2 queues, one that stores items read form the the input file and one that stores processed item to be written to one output file.
I can use your code to 'exit' from the blocking read of the first queue, but then i have no way to signal the second queue.
Maybe with a global synchronization primitive (per job) i could signal to both queues.. I'll have to try it later. I'll mark it as answer anyway because it should work on a simpler scenario

Comment: Couldn't you similarly pass a poison pill from queue 1 to queue 2?

Comment: Sorry, got moved to another problem. 
I can't pass the poison pill between queues because they are in different steps and the only way to pass data is using the job/step context or some other "global" context. there's no way, that i know of of, to directly pass data between steps.

Comment: Along those lines, I suppose you could pass a singleton `AtomicBoolean` wherever you need it and then use that to signal across threads/steps.

Comment: Yeah, seems a bit 'hacky' but still haven't found a cleaner way. Next refactor I'll be trying that. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

So, i'm going to post my solution in case anyone is interested or faces a similar problem.

I, summary i ended up using a Poison Pill as Dean Clark suggested.
I eventually simplified the job to only use one BlockingQueue, but i still had the problem of how to inject the Poison Pill, since it's a queue shared between steps, not inside one single step..

Basically, instead of mucking around the Readers to return the Poison Pill, and the processors to detect it and ignore it, i just let Spring Batch run normally and i just added a listener to the Step responsible for injecting the Poison Pill. This listener overrides "afterStep" and just adds it to the Queue.
The Step reading from the Queue will get the Poison Pill and the end of the Queue, signifying "no more work to do" and will terminate normally, by returning null.

Another 'quirk' to this is that in one Job, the Step that reads from the Queue is configured with a ThreadPool to process items in parallel so i need to kill/unblock all the threads reading from the Queue. A nice trick was having the Reader read from the Queue and if it's a Poison Pill, just re-inject it into the Queue and return null. This way every thread get's a Poison Pill and terminates properly.